# db append a certain value to a particular field for all records

Tags: sql, database, informix

I have a groups table which has a field called permissions that has a pipe separated value.
for example

```
permissions='1-1|2-2|3-2|4-2|5-2|6-2|7-1|8-2|9-2|10-2|11-2|12-2|13-3|14-2|15-2|16-2|
```

Now I want to append the following values to all permissions field in the groups table:
|17-0|18-0|19-0

So i need something like

`UPDATE groups SET permissions='existing value+|17-0|18-0|19-0';`

I am not sure how to go about it.( I am using informix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a bit about this, in  informix concatenation with null gives null. If the field permissions can be null, the update needs to be changed a bit.

```
UPDATE groups SET permissions = NVL(permissions || '|17-0|18-0|19-0', '17-0|18-0|19-0');
```

If permissions can't be null, then this is enough:

```
UPDATE groups SET permissions = permissions || '|17-0|18-0|19-0';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE groups SET permissions = permissions + '|17-0|18-0|19-0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Google says, use ConCat command or ||